# Expected value of Discrete Random Variable taking non-numeric values.

Tags: probability-theory

Can one define the expected value of a random variable whos domain is not numeric in some way?

For example, lets consider an urn with two balls, red and blue with equal probabilities of being drawn and $X$ the random variable representing the color of the ball drawn.

Can we assign some form of expected value to the outcome?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "urn," not "urine."

Comment: I think the expected value would be "purple".

Comment: @ Sean oh yes, I wasn't watching lol.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I was blinking at that for longer than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 3):

The domain has to be numeric "enough" that it makes sense to add such quantities together, and to multiply them by numbers in $[0,1]$, because the Expected Value does these operations to compute an "average" of the outcomes.

An example of such a space is $\mathbb{R}^n,$ or $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$), or anything that can be viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}.$ We could talk about defining Expected Values of Random variables whose codomain is an algebraic structure satisfying the required properties, but the main story is that usually we try to map the exotic codomains (e.g. colours) to suitable real numbers (e.g. wavelength) and work with real numbers instead.